# What could I use as a model light?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, studio-lighting, strobes, studio-setup, strobist

Hello I use various speedlights (8-9 nikon models, time ago I had the need for more flexibility)...

These days I got back shooting in studio and while I do own various modifiers that would like a bit more power using the speedlights is still ok...

**The real problem is the lack of a continuos modeling light...**

Being able to see in realtime what I'm doing would be really handy in some shootings.

There's any option open to me in order to add a modeling light to my setup?

I've considered to buy new heads but they are very costly. There's maybe an alternative like adding a [small powered led light](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B094QCVPZT) inside the softboxes to simulate a model light, could it work? There are valid low cost heads that I should consider, what you would do to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

If operating in a studio, then it's really hard to argue against mains powered studio strobes. Something like Godox 300WS strobes are far more suitable than any array of speedlights and cheaper.

If the modeling lights are not proportional they don't provide much help other than placement/angles... i.e. adding a secondary constant light to your speedlights/modifiers won't help more than that and will be a faff.

Another option for that is to place a light at the camera's position and then move around the subject... when you see the light on the subject where you want it that is where you place your light/modifier. Basically, it's using one light as a placement modeling light for multiple lights.

Comment: Yes, mains powered Godox 300WS monolights cost less than many speedlights these days.  Even the $109 MS300 has a 150W modeling light proportionally adjustable from 5% to 100% brightness and a built-in Godox 2.4MHz radio receiver.

Answer (score 2):

Buy a clamp-on LED bed lamp or from the hardware store, a clamp on lamp with aluminum reflector. The modeling light is just an ordinary lamp that plays on the subject from about the same distance as the flash it is replicating. The idea is to pre-visualize the effect of the flash.